# Change action menu text color and reduce spacing toolbar android?

Tags: android, menu, styles, themes, toolbar

I am using the toolbar with navigation view for side menu

I also have 2 action menu items of which one denotes a numeric value and other is an image.

I need to reduce the spacing between those 2 menuitems and also change the color of the item text.

[image]

This is my activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is theme file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!-- Set proper title size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
    <!-- Set title color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

This is the menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/lollyMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/jar"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/Amt"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="0"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
 </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try negative margin and textColor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/lollyMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/jar"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/Amt"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="0"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dp" />
 </menu>
```